# Update value if the checkbox if checked multiple rows php

Tags: php, html, sql

I am trying to update each row with a value of 1 if the checkbox is checked and do nothing if not.

[image]

```html
$query= "SELECT Name, Surname, Age, Club, age_group, School, team_select FROM players WHERE Age < 9";
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$players = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo '<form nethod="POST" action="add_to_team.php">';
echo '<p align="center"><a href="new.php" >Add Player</a></p>';
echo '<table class="table table-bordered"';
echo '<tr><th>Name</th>
      <th>Surname</th>
      <th>Club</th>
      <th>Age Group</th>
      <th>School</th>
      <th>Edit</th>
      <th>Delete</th>
      <th>Add to Team</th></tr>';


// loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
 foreach ($players as $player) {
// echo out the contents of each row into a table
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>' . $player['Name'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $player['Surname'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $player['Club'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $player['age_group'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $player['School'] . '</td>';
echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id=' . $player['Name'] . '">Edit</a></td>';
echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id=' . $player['Name'] . '">Delete</a></td>';
echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="team_select" value="1"> </td>';


echo '</tr>';

}
echo '</table>';
echo'<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"><br/>';
```

Code (It just won't work)

```html
<?php
include 'connect.php';//database connection
isset($_POST['team_select'])
?>
```

Comment: `isset($_POST['team_select'])` does nothing on its own - Where is the insert or update statement?
also never call anything `name="submit"`. What is the expected and actual output of this code

Comment: Apart from `isset($_POST['team_select'])` where is the other code?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz I think Cindi wants us to just provide that part...

Comment: That is where I am stuck I will post all the different ways I have tried I keep getting error on error so it is a lot hence why I did not post it. Give me a sec will post it.

Comment: Start by naming the checkbox `team_select[]` which will automatically make an array for PHP to consume and give the value the player id or team select

Comment: Also NEVER EVER have a delete in a link. One visit of google bot and all your players are deleted

Comment: include 'connect.php';//database connection
if(gettype($_POST['team_select'])=="array"){
foreach($_POST['team_select'] as $val){
 $team=$val;
 $query="update players set team_select='1' where id='".$team."'";
}
}

Comment: Please update your question instead of posing comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the checkboxes different names. If they're all named `team_select` there will just be one `$_POST['team_select']`, but you won't be able to tell which checkboxes were checked.

Use `name="team_select[]"` and they'll all be put into an array. Then you can put the player name into the `value`, so the array will contain the names of all the players who should be added.

```
echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="team_select[]" value="' . $player['Name'] . '"> </td>';
```

When you're processing the form, you can do:

```
foreach ($_POST['team_select'] as $name) {
    ...
}
```

to process all the players who were selected.